# Do you have to use the article "the" when the location of the thing in question is determinate?

Tags: grammar

> "The hair on his face reminded me of a dog's fur."
>
> **> "Hair on his face reminded me of a dog's fur."**
>
> "The eyes on his face reminded me of the devil's eyes."
>
> **> "Eyes on his face reminded me of the devil's eyes."**

The bolded phrasing seems to be wrong, or is it? I am not quite sure, but it seems that if the location is determinate and use the article "the" or the determining possessive pronoun "his" the thing in question must also use a determining possessive pronoun "his" or the article "the".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, both versions are acceptable, but they change the meaning of the sentence subtly.

'The' is omitted when talking of things in a general sense. So, I would expect it when used in the following context:

> Hair on one's face is a fashion *faux pas*.

We are talking in general about hair on anybody's face. In effect we are using the plural indefinite article.

When talking about a specific person's hair, it is more natural and correct-sounding to add the definite article.

> *The* hair on *his* face ...

In the examples you give, the difference is very slight, but there are circumstances where it makes a bigger distinction.

There is an [interesting answer here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239585/why-do-people-omit-the-definite-article) about the full complexity of articles in English, and the 'zero' and 'null' articles. In effect you are saying something like:

> [An amount of/some] hair on his face reminded me of ...